# How to show all StyleCop warnings for a solution?

Tags: c#, msbuild, project, stylecop, solution

If I have 2 projects in my solution, and each one of them is configured to run StyleCop, MSBuild will show only warnings for a single project.

Isn't there a way to make it show warnings for every project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use msbuidl and the msbuild extension pack, specifically: MSBuild.ExtensionPack.StyleCop.dll

to analyse a path (alll the code here) e.g.

and send the files to the task

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.CodeQuality.StyleCop
     TaskAction="Scan"
      ShowOutput="true"
      ForceFullAnalysis="true"
      CacheResults="false"
      SourceFiles="@(SourceFiles)"
      SettingsFile="$(SourceAnalysisSettingsFile)"
      ContinueOnError="false">
             <Output TaskParameter="Succeeded" PropertyName="AllPassed"/>
             <Output TaskParameter="ViolationCount" PropertyName="Violations"/>
             <Output TaskParameter="FailedFiles" ItemName="Failures"/>

</MSBuild.ExtensionPack.CodeQuality.StyleCop>
```

Hope that gets you started.